# PostgreSql round() giving Error

Tags: postgresql

I have this query

```
SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(discount_rate * 0.1, 2), '0') AS discount_amount,
COALESCE(discount_rate, 0) AS discount_rate 
FROM discount_rate
```

and it is giving me the following error when execute throught my application code however it works fine on SQLManagerLite Query panel.

```
Error Code (80007) ERROR: function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: use `ROUND(discount_rate::numeric * 0.1, 2)`

Comment: @Mike: No I actually use ::Numeric in the code query and it says you need explicit casting and when I did SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(CAST (discount_rate * 0.1) AS NUMERIC, 2), '0') AS discount_amount,
    COALESCE(discount_rate, 0) AS discount_rate 
    FROM discount_rate                  it gives error Error Code (80007) ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"       however i am unable to figure out the last error